# use s2ram when closing lid with kde

Tags: 11.04, laptop, kde, suspend

When I ask kde to suspend to ram on my laptop, it does not resume properly. However, I installed `uswsusp` and `sudo s2ram -f -a 3` works. Is there a way to tell kde that it is supposed to run this command line when closing the lid instead of having to use the console each time?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit (or create if it doesn't exist) the file `/etc/pm/config.d/module` and add the following content:

```
SLEEP_MODULE=uswsusp
```

As well as the file `/etc/pm/config.d/defaults` with the following content:

```
S2RAM_OPTS="-f"
```

All suspend functions should now work using s2ram.

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1847872)